# How to make query parameters optional

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

In Postgres in Go, how can I make query parameters optional?

In this example `status` is an optional condition. If no `status` is passed all rows from table records will be fetched.

How to make query parameter `&d.Status` an optional

```
type QueryParams struct {
    Status string `json:"status"`
}

func (r repo) GetRecords(d *QueryParams) ([]*Records, error) {
    statusQuery := ""

    if d.Status != "" {
        statusQuery = " where status = $1 "
    }

    query := "select id, title, status from records " + statusQuery
    rows, err := r.db.Query(query, &d.Status)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[`Query`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query) is variadic so you could build an `[]interface{}` to hold the arguments:

```
args := []interface{}{}
```

and then to conditionally build the argument list:

```
if d.Status != "" {
    statusQuery = " where status = $1 "
    args = append(args, &d.Status)
}
```

When you run the query, expand the arguments using `...`:

```
rows, err := r.db.Query(query, args...)
```

Comment: This worked for me! (Though in my case I appended the actual value, d.Status, rather than its address, &d.Status). Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You may use a flexible `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
SELECT id, title, status
FROM records
WHERE status = $1 OR $1 IS NULL;
```

The logic here is that if you provide a value for `$1`, it must match the status in order for a record to be returned.  Otherwise, if `$1` be left out (i.e. is `NULL`), then all records would be returned.

Note that to make this work from Go with the Postgres driver, you may need to do some extra massaging.  I would try, at a first attempt, this:

```
statusQuery = "where status = $1 or $1::text is null"
query := "select id, title, status from records " + statusQuery
rows, err := r.db.Query(query, &d.Status)
```

Sometimes the driver can't figure out the type of the bound parameter `$1`.  By explicitly casting it to `text`, the statement can be made to work.

Comment: It's valid, it's just irrelevant to the question actually being asked. They've already got their dynamic SQL query working, they just need to know how to pass in the values for the parameters when executing the query.

Comment: `If no status is passed all rows from table records will be fetched.` ... my answer seems to meet this requirement.  No, the OP doesn't already have the query working, or else they would not have asked this question.

Comment: Their code *already meets that requirement* if you actually read it. The entire `WHERE` clause is programmatically added to the query when needed. This answer is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I had the same question as the OP and I found this answer helpful. It is often useful to have different strategies to choose from.